# MySQL Inner join naming error?

Tags: mysql, sql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6effb/1

I'm trying to get a top 10 by revenue per brand for France on december.
There are 2 tables (first table has date, second table has brand and I'm trying to join them)

I get this error "FUNCTION db_9_d870e5.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual"

Is my use of Inner join there correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you had an extra space after `SUM`. Please change it from

`SUM (o1.total_net_revenue)`to `SUM(o1.total_net_revenue)`.

See more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

Also after correcting it, your query still had more error as you were not selecting `order_id` on your intermediate table `i2` so edited here as :

```
SELECT o1.order_id, o1.country, i2.brand,
SUM(o1.total_net_revenue)
FROM orders o1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT i1.brand, SUM(i1.net_revenue) AS total_net_revenue,order_id
    FROM ordered_items i1
    WHERE i1.country = 'France'
    GROUP BY i1.brand
    ) i2 
ON o1.order_id = i2.order_id AND o1.total_net_revenue = i2.total_net_revenue
AND o1.total_net_revenue = i2.total_net_revenue
WHERE o1.country = 'France' AND o1.created_at BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2016-12-31'
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 4
LIMIT 10`
```

Answer (score 0):

--EDIT stack Fan is correct that the o2.total_net_revenue exists. My confusion was because the data structure duplicated three columns between the tables, including one that was being looked for.

There were a couple errors with your SQL statement:

<strike>1. You were referencing an invalid column in your outer-select-SUM function. I believe you're actually after i2.total_net_revenue.</strike>

1. The table structure is terrible, the "important" columns (country, revenue, order_id) are duplicated between the two tables. I would also expect the revenue columns to share the same name, if they always have the same values in them. In the example, there's no difference between i1.net_revenue and o1.total_net_revenue.
2. In your inner join, you didn't reference i1.order_id, which meant that your "on" clause couldn't execute correctly.

PROTIP:
When you run into an issue like this, take all the complicated bits out of your query and get the base query working correctly first. THEN add your functions.

PROTIP:
In your GROUP BY clause, reference the actual columns, NOT the column numbers. It makes your query more robust.

This is the query I ended up with:

```
SELECT o1.order_id, o1.country, i2.brand,
SUM(i2.total_net_revenue) AS total_rev
FROM orders o1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT i1.order_id, i1.brand, SUM(i1.net_revenue) AS total_net_revenue
    FROM ordered_items i1
    WHERE i1.country = 'France'
    GROUP BY i1.brand
    ) i2 
    ON o1.order_id = i2.order_id AND o1.total_net_revenue = i2.total_net_revenue
    AND o1.total_net_revenue = i2.total_net_revenue
WHERE o1.country = 'France' AND o1.created_at BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2016-12-31'
GROUP BY o1.order_id, o1.country, i2.brand
ORDER BY total_rev
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: He can still select `SUM(o1.total_net_revenue)` if he removes the space on the query.

Comment: No he can't, I tried it in SQLFiddle. He still has to add o1.order_id to the inner join select.

Comment: Yeah after adding `o1.order_id`. I was just mentioning that your #1 reason might not be true because he can select that if he uses necessary join.

Comment: Good catch... I looked at the structure too quickly to see!

Comment: In fact.... the simplest way to write the query is as follows:

`SELECT o1.order_id, o1.country, i2.brand,
SUM(o1.total_net_revenue)
FROM orders o1
inner join ordered_items i2 on i2.order_id = o1.order_id and i2.country = o1.country
WHERE o1.country = 'France' AND o1.created_at BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2016-12-31'
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 4
LIMIT 10`

Comment: And I'm not sold that o1.total_net_revenue is what you want....

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fae624/1

Comment: Indeed. We can only assume as the asker has not clearly mentioned what he wants. He just encountered an error and wanted to know about it.